# Merge sort linked list algorithm c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am still young at C++ and having some trouble with a code for algorithm aimed at merge-sorting a linked list and recursively remove the largest value element during each loop (a data of six elements so expecting six times print out of the actions). I tried to get my job using just two functions (void show and void deleteLargest). But couldn't get through after multiple attempts. Where did I go wrong with the following code please?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#define S 8

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age[S];
    int next[S];
    void show(int *age, int *next);
    void deleteLargest(int *next);

    age[1] = 9;
    age[2] = 12;
    age[3] = 7;
    age[4] = 15;
    age[5] = 8;
    age[6] = 11;

    next[0] = 3;
    next[1] = 6;
    next[2] = 4;
    next[3] = 5;
    next[4] = -1;
    next[5] = 1;
    next[6] = 2;

    show(age, next);
    deleteLargest(next);
    show(age, next);
    deleteLargest(next);
    show(age, next);
    deleteLargest(next);
    show(age, next);
    deleteLargest(next);
    show(age, next);
    deleteLargest(next);
    show(age, next);


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

My main problem is with the following functions probably with both the show and the deleteLargest functions but didn't get passed the show function though as it was failing. The main target is to list the main elements (age) in ascending order in each step along with deleting the largest value at each loop until only one element is left (age with a value of 7 in this case).

```
void show(int *age, int *next) {  // print the results
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Show effect of the action taken:\n " << endl;
    if (next[0] != 6) {
        cout << age[next[0]] << endl;
        for (int i = 0, nextIndex = next[0]; i < S - 1; i++) {
            nextIndex = next[nextIndex];
            if (nextIndex == 3) {
                break;
            }
            cout << age[nextIndex] << endl;
        }
    }
}

void deleteLargest(int *next) {
    for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
        if (next[i] == 6) {
            if (i == 0) {
                cout << "Deleted All.";
                break;
            }
            next[i] = -2; // not used

            for (int j = 0; j < S; j++) {
                if (next[j] == i) {
                    next[j] = 6;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

These is how my arrays look like:

            `[0]     [1]     [2]     [3]     [4]     [5]     [6] 
next(int)    3       6       4       5       -1      1       2
age(int)             9      12       7       15      8       11`

I have tried the following code for the two functions as per rcgldr's recommendation but it seems not working for me :(

```
    void deleteLargest(int *next) {
        for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
            if (next[i] == -1) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    cout << "Deleted all except age 7.";
                    break;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < S; j++) {
                    if (next[j] == i) {
                        next[j] = -1;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of two independent, unrelated arrays what you really want is one array of `struct` elements that contain all necessary properties.

Comment: I can try that separately but isn't it possible to make this work? I mean the two functions. I was just trying to manipulate the indices (to link the two arrays through their respective indices).  For example in the 'next' array, element 5 has index 3 (where I tried to start) and the 5 of 'next' array is linked to 7 of the 'age' array. And then value of index 5 of the 'next' array is linked to 8 of 'age' array which obviously will come next during sorting etc. I will edit the question with the linked list may be.

Comment: You're making it twice as hard as it should be by trying to manipulate two arrays in parallel. This would also be a lot cleaner if you used `std::vector` instead of these arbitrary, fixed-length arrays.

Comment: See [Merge Sort for Linked Lists](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/).

Comment: Both function should start at the "dummy" element next[0]. The list function should advance through next until a negative value is reached. To delete an element, change the link that points to that element to point to the next element, which would remove it from the list. If deleting the last element, in this case next[4], then set the prior element (next[2]) to -1.